# How do I switch focus in The Lost Vikings on Genesis?

Tags: the-lost-vikings

I'm playing 3-player Lost Vikings on Genesis.  I read online that, in the SNES version, you can "give" the camera to somebody else by pressing L+R.  I tried X+Z (both switch-player buttons) but it doesn't seem to work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try the select button? That would seem to be the most obvious button to use.

Comment: Trying to fix the tag, "lost-viking" refers to something from Starcraft II. This game is called "The Lost Vikings".

Comment: @Zibbobz - Not sure if trolling. Where is the select button?!! http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Sega-Genesis-6But-Cont.jpg

Comment: @Cory J Huh...could've swron the Sega controller had a Select button.

Answer (score 5):

To switch Vikings on the Genesis:

3 button controller:

```
Start + D-Pad Left or Right
```

6 button controller:

```
X or Z
```

I personally have always had the three button controllers. I found [this article](http://www.allgame.com/game.php?id=1623&tab=controls) for assistance on the controls for The Lost Vikings on Genesis.

On an unrelated note, this is one of the best childhood  memories for me.

**Edit**: I was misunderstanding that you were doing the three player extension. In this case to switch between players you have to use:

```
A + B + C
```

This will cause undesired actions to happen, I don't know if this was overlooked when the game was published for the Genesis or not.

More on this information can be found on this [website](http://tasvideos.org/1298S.html).

Comment: Right, but with 3 players nobody can "switch vikings".  The camera follows the last viking standing -- if everybody dies, the last one down gets the camera on the next play-through.  Sometimes, you want to stick the camera to another player.  I found [this question](http://www.gamefaqs.com/snes/562633-lost-vikings-2/answers?qid=235902) on Gamefaqs about Lost Vikings 2 on SNES -- that's the closest I've come so far.  Maybe it's just not possible?  Seems like a big oversight if that's the case.

Comment: See my edit about using A+B+C on the Genesis. This is kind of a pain from what I understand. I would recommend not having any inventory item selected before doing this and if you do have something selected in your inventory I would choose something that can be wasted.

Comment: And on Switch port of improved Genesis port of this SNES game it turns out to be L+R.